# How to hide a variable depending on the value of another variable without MonoBehaviour In Unity Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

I have a class that I would like to hide the float "segmentEnd" depending on the value of the bool "isAStillFrame".

The reason I can not use MonoBehaviour is because I need the class "VideoSegment" to be in a serialized list in the script the VideoSegment is in. Is this possible? Right now changing the value of isAStillFrame does nothing.

Class to Modify

`code`

```
public class VideoSegment
{
    public string segmentName;
    public bool isAStillFrame;
    public float segmentStart;
    public float segmentEnd;
    public List<VideoSegmentCue> segmentCues;
    public VideoSegmentAction endAction;
}
```

`code`

Editor Script that is in the Editor Folder

`code`

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

    [CustomEditor(typeof(VideoSegment)), CanEditMultipleObjects]
    public class SegmentedVideoPlayerEditor : Editor
    {
        private List<boolStruct> structList;

        public void OnEnable()
        {
            structList = new List<boolStruct>();
            SetBools();
        }

        private void SetBools()
        {
            HideIf("isAStillFrame", true, "segmentEnd");
        }

        private void HideIf(string boolName, bool boolValue, string fieldName)
        {
            boolStruct _boolStruct = new boolStruct()
            {
                targetBoolName = boolName,
                targetBoolValue = boolValue,
                targetVarName = fieldName,
            };
            structList.Add(_boolStruct);
        }
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();
            var obj = serializedObject.GetIterator();
            if (obj.NextVisible(true))
            {
                do
                {
                    bool visible = true;
                    foreach (var i in structList)
                    {
                        if (i.targetVarName == obj.name)
                        {
                            FieldInfo boolName = target.GetType().GetField(i.targetBoolName);
                            var boolValue = boolName.GetValue(target);
                            if (boolValue.ToString() != i.targetBoolValue.ToString())
                                visible = false;
                            else
                            {
                                visible = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (visible)
                        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(obj, true);
                }
                while (obj.NextVisible(false));
            }
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
        private struct boolStruct
        {
            public string targetBoolName { get; set; }
            public bool targetBoolValue { get; set; }
            public string targetVarName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject` (or in general from `UnityEngine.Object`) then a custom [`Editor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html) is the wrong tool to use.

`Editor` is for implementing an entire *Inspector* for a certain selectable **asset** type.

What you rather want to go with is a custom [`PropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) which might look like e.g.

```
// First of all your class needs to be serializable
// otherwise it won't show up in the Inspector at all
[Serializable]
public class VideoSegment
{
    public string segmentName;
    public bool isAStillFrame;
    public float segmentStart;
    public float segmentEnd;
    public List<VideoSegmentCue> segmentCues;
    public VideoSegmentAction endAction;
}
```

and then

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(VideoSegment))]
public class VideoSegmentDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    // First you have to define how much vertical space your custom drawer should reserve 
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        // I simply assume you want to fold your type so in this case
        // it would be only the foldout label
        if (!property.isExpanded)
        {
            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        }

        // link up the properties
        var segmentName = property.FindPropertyRelative("segmentName");
        var isAStillFrame = property.FindPropertyRelative("isAStillFrame");
        var segmentStart = property.FindPropertyRelative("segmentStart");
        var segmentEnd = property.FindPropertyRelative("segmentEnd");
        var segmentCues = property.FindPropertyRelative("segmentCues");
        var endAction = property.FindPropertyRelative("endAction");

        // assuming we later on use the default drawers for all properties
        // we an also just use the default heights for them
        return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight
            + EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(segmentName)
            + EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(isAStillFrame)
            + EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(segmentStart)
            // if your bool is checked we want to skip this field later
            // so we also don't need the space for it
            + (isAStillFrame.boolValue ? 0 : EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(segmentEnd))
            + EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(segmentCues)
            + EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(endAction);
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        // Using BeginProperty / EndProperty on the parent property means that
        // prefab override logic works on the entire property.
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        // calculate rect for the foldout label
        var labelRect = position;
        labelRect.height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // Draw foldout label
        property.isExpanded = EditorGUI.Foldout(labelRect, property.isExpanded, label);
        
        // if expanded draw the rest
        if (property.isExpanded)
        {
            // again link up poperties
            var segmentName = property.FindPropertyRelative("segmentName");
            var isAStillFrame = property.FindPropertyRelative("isAStillFrame");
            var segmentStart = property.FindPropertyRelative("segmentStart");
            var segmentEnd = property.FindPropertyRelative("segmentEnd");
            var segmentCues = property.FindPropertyRelative("segmentCues");
            var endAction = property.FindPropertyRelative("endAction");
 
            // indentation - I was lazy to look it up so just used an arbitrary value
            position.x += 5;
            position.width -= 5;

            // Calculate rect and draw segmentName
            var segmentNameRect = position;
            segmentNameRect.height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(segmentName);
            position.y += segmentNameRect.height;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(segmentNameRect, segmentName);

            // Calculate rect and draw isAStillFrame
            var isAStillFrameRect = position;
            isAStillFrameRect.height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(isAStillFrame);
            position.y += isAStillFrameRect.height;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(isAStillFrameRect, isAStillFrame);

            // Calculate rect and draw segmentStart
            var segmentStartRect = position;
            segmentStartRect.height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(segmentStart);
            position.y += segmentStartRect.height;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(segmentStartRect, segmentStart);

            // skip if your bool is set
            if (!isAStillFrame.boolValue)
            {
                // Calculate rect and draw segmentEnd
                var segmentEndRect = position;
                segmentEndRect.height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(segmentEnd);
                position.y += segmentEndRect.height;
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(segmentEndRect, segmentEnd);
            }

            // Calculate rect and draw segmentCues
            var segmentCuesRect = position;
            segmentCuesRect.height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(segmentCues);
            position.y += segmentCuesRect.height;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(segmentCuesRect, segmentCues);

            // Calculate rect and draw endAction
            var endActionRect = position;
            endActionRect.height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(endAction);
            position.y += endActionRect.height;
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(endActionRect, endAction);
        }

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

This would look like

*NOTE: I don't have your types `VideoSegmentCue` and `VideoSegmentAction` so I just used `Vector3` for the demo ;)*

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VideoSegment singleSegment;

    public List<VideoSegment> listOfSegments;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me so quickly @PeterSmith ! I am new here so thank you for dealing with anything I left out. This is working for me for the most part, I think I can learn from the code you provided to make it work with VideoSegmentCue and VideoSegmentAction as well. Sorry for not including those originally . I can post those as well but it will lead us down a different rabbit hole.